# Number of actions of $\mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $X$ be a finite set. Determine the number of actions of $\mathbb Z$ on $X$.

If $X$ is a finite set with $|X|=m$, then $|\{f:X \to X : \text{f is bijective}\}|=m!$.

Finding the number of actions is counting the number of morphisms $\phi:\mathbb Z \to Sym(X)$. By the condition $\phi(1)=Id_{Sym(x)}$ and the fact that $\phi$ is a morphism, we have $\phi(n)=\phi(1+...+1)=Id_{Sym(X)} \circ ... \circ Id_{Sym(X)}=Id_{Sym(X)}$, so there is an only possible action which is the "trivial" action, which is $g.x=x$ for all $g \in \mathbb Z$, $x \in X$.

I would like to verify if my solution is correct.

Comment: There is no condition that $1\in\Bbb Z$ act trivially. While $1$ is the multiplicative identity, when we treat the integers $\Bbb Z$ as an *additive* group we do not see multiplication, we see addition, and $1$ is not the additive identity. Rather, $0$ is the additive identity, so $0$ is the thing that acts trivially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by @anon, your solution is incorrect. In some sense you had a fruitful idea by focussing on $\phi(1)$, but you applied that focus incorrectly by confusing additive and multiplicative notation.

Instead, use the fact that for any group $G$ with group operation denoted $g \cdot h$, a homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to G$ is completely determined by the value of the single element $\phi(1) \in G$, because 
$$\phi(n) = \phi(\,\underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_{\text{($n$-times)}}\,) = \underbrace{\phi(1) \cdot \ldots \cdot \phi(1)}_{\text{($n$-times)}} = \phi(1)^n
$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I think I can: if $n>0$, then, as you and I've said previously, $\phi(n)=\phi(1)^n$, so the values the function $\phi$ takes on positive integers is completely determined by $\phi(1)$. If $n$ is negative, can I say the same thing? I mean, if $n<0$, then $-n>0$, so $\phi(-n)=\phi(1)^{-n}$. Can I deduce from here that the values on the negative integers are also completely determined by $\phi(1)$? If that is the case, then $\phi(1)$ can take $m!$ different values, so the number of actions is $m!$. Is my statement correct?

Comment: @user16924: That's correct. Group homomorphisms preserve the inverse operation. This is written as $\phi(-n)=\phi(n)^{-1}$ in the current situation where we use additive notation in the domain and multiplicative notation in the range.