# Number of distinct group actions

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-homomorphism

I am trying to solve a problem of group action that

What is number of distinct actions of the group $\mathbb{Z}$ on the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$?

Here my understanding is, for the group action there will be a permutation representative such that

$$\phi: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow S_4$$

And to know the number of distinct group action I need to know how many possible $\phi$s are there.

Now, I am confused, how I can determine the the number of $\phi$, or am I going in wrong direction?

Comment: I assume we're talking about $\Bbb Z$ under addition, in which case every group action will be completely determined by the action of $1$ on the set.  That should help you simplify the analysis.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I see I misread the question. Anyways this question needs context and details/clarity--hence my vote to close. How does an element $\mathbb{Z}$ act on $\{1,2,3,4\}$. By filling in these details you may end up answering your own question.

Comment: See a similar question [Number of actions of $\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918962/number-of-actions-of-mathbb-z?rq=1)